# multiprocessing.Pool returns different length of output compared to the input iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I wrote a Python program which I want to parallelize using `multiprocessing.Pool` when calling the program (`MyProgram.__call__()`). The expected output is a list of dictionaries (`dicts`) with the same length as the input list `images`. However, when I test it with input with length 60 using `multiprocessing.Pool` of 20 cpus, I got an output with only length 41.

Below is my code:

```
from acat.utilities import neighbor_shell_list, get_adj_matrix, get_max_delta_sum_path
from acat.build.adlayer import StochasticPatternGenerator as SPG
from acat.build.ordering import RandomOrderingGenerator as ROG
from ase.build import fcc111
from ase.io import read
from multiprocessing import Pool
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import os

class MyProgram(object):

    def __init__(self, alpha=.75, n_jobs=os.cpu_count()):
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.n_jobs = n_jobs

    def __call__(self, images):
        # Parallelization
        pool = Pool(self.n_jobs)
        dicts = pool.map(self.get_dict, images)
        return dicts

    def get_dict(self, atoms):
        d = {}
        numbers = atoms.numbers
        nblist = neighbor_shell_list(atoms, dx=0.3, neighbor_number=1, mic=True)
        A = get_adj_matrix(nblist)
        for i in range(len(A)):
            nbrs = np.where(A[i] == 1)[0]
            An = A[nbrs,:][:,nbrs]
            Gn = nx.from_numpy_matrix(An)
            path = max(nx.all_simple_paths(Gn, source=0, target=next(Gn.neighbors(0))),
                       key=lambda x: len(x))
            path_numbers = list(numbers[nbrs[path]])
            sorted_numbers = get_max_delta_sum_path(path_numbers)
            lab1 = str(numbers[i])
            lab2 = lab1 + ':' + ','.join(map(str, sorted_numbers))
            labs = [lab1, lab2]
            for idx, lab in enumerate(labs):
                if idx == 0:
                    factor = 1
                elif idx == 1:
                    factor = self.alpha
                if lab in d:
                    d[lab] += factor
                else:
                    d[lab] = factor
        return d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MP = MyProgram(alpha=.75, n_jobs=20)
    slab = fcc111('Pt', (4, 4, 4))
    slab.center(vacuum=5., axis=2)
    rog = ROG(slab, elements=['Ni', 'Pt'])
    rog.run(num_gen=10)
    slabs = read('orderings.traj', index=':')
    spg = SPG(slabs, surface='fcc111',
              adsorbate_species=['CO','OH','C'],
              min_adsorbate_distance=3.,
              composition_effect=True)
    spg.run(num_gen=60, action='add', unique=False)
    images = read('patterns.traj', index=':')
    dicts = MP(images)
    print(len(images))
    print(len(dicts))
```

Output

```
60
41
```

Does anyone know why is `multiprocessing.Pool` returning an output of different length from the input? Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this phenomenon when using simplified code. But in case anyone wants to run my code, you only need to install `acat` by `pip3 install acat`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing **call** to be:

```
with Pool(self.n_jobs) as pool:
    dicts = pool.map(self.get_dict, images)
return dicts
```

I suspect that the problem is that `__call__` returns before all the jobs are done.  `len` may somehow be only seeing the completed jobs rather than all of them.

Comment: I'm not so sure this is the problem, (though I'm not 100% sure, and using `with ` is good practice anyway). `pool.map` ought to wait for the correct number of outputs in general. It takes `len(iterable)` at the beginning of computation, and waits for that many results...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this still doesn't fix the issue. I also tried ``pool.close()`` and ``pool.terminate()``, but neither helps. When I tried to ``print(d)`` in each ``self.get_dict``, it only prints out 14 results, even less than the length of the output. Very confusing.

Comment: Sorry. It was worth a shot.  This is really strange.

Comment: @FrankYellin I have figured it out. It's the problem with ``next(Gn.neighbors(0))``. Since some of these generators are empty, it will raise the ``StopIteration`` error, but for some reason this error doesn't show in ``multiprocessing.Pool``. I will start a vote to close this post.

Comment: I wonder if there's a bug in multiprocessing.Pool that needs to be reported.   I'm glad you found the problem.  There really is no need to close this question.